# Filter column only if field is a number (datatables)

Tags: jquery, filter, datatable, datatables

I am using DataTables jQuery plugin to show my data retrieved from my service; I have a case where I have to enter a number and filter based on this number in a column which fields may contain the first character as a Letter. I want to filter column without getting fields with letters; Ex:
If I have in my column values like : **B123** - **C753** - **356** I want to enter **3** and return **only 356**; Is this is possible?

Below is my code:

```
function filterMySecondColumn() {
    $('#my_tbl').DataTable().column(2).search(
        $('#My_Val').val(), // my value to be filtered => it is 3 in the example
           false,
           true
        ).draw();
}
```

With the above code: returned result will be **B123** - **C753** - **356** as they all contain **3**.

**Edit:**

Below is my Html; When I click on button Filter, multiple functions to filter will be called. One of them is 'filterMySecondColumn'. Please note that my table is filled through a service using ajax, but below is a template.

```
<table id="tblHeaderHomePage" class="tblHeaderHomePage" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="filter_col1" data-column="0">
            <td class="FilterTdTitle">
                Column 0
            </td>
            <td class="FilterTdContent">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm HomePage_Filter_Input"
                    id="col0_filter" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="filter_col2" data-column="1">
            <td class="FilterTdTitle">
                Column 1
            </td>
            <td class="FilterTdContent">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm HomePage_Filter_Input"
                    style="width: 85px" id="DateFrom" />
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm HomePage_Filter_Input"
                    style="width: 85px" id="DateTo" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="filter_col3" data-column="2">
            <td class="FilterTdTitle">
                Column 2
            </td>
            <td class="FilterTdContent">                                
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm HomePage_Filter_Input" id="col2_filter" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="filter_col4" data-column="3">
            <td class="FilterTdTitle">
                 Column 3
            </td>
            <td class="FilterTdContent">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm HomePage_Filter_Input"
                    id="col3_filter" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="filter_col5" data-column="4">
            <td class="FilterTdTitle">
                Column 4
            </td>
            <td class="FilterTdContent">
                <select class="BAN_Select_Home" id="Status_Select">
                    <option value="All">All</option>                                    
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="BAN_HomePage_Filter_buttons_div">
    <input type="button" class="BAN_HomePage_Filter_buttons" onclick="filter()" value="Filter" />                    
</div>

<table id="My_tbl_init" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Column 0
            </th>
            <th>
                Column 1
            </th>
            <th>
                Column 2
            </th>
            <th>
                Column 3
            </th>
            <th>
                Column 3
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="My_tbl">

    <tr>
        <td>
            test1
        </td>
        <td>
             06/10/2017
        </td>
        <td>
            B123
        </td>
        <td>
            Opened
        </td>                       
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            test2
        </td>
        <td>
            06/10/2017
        </td>
        <td>
            C789
        </td>
        <td>
            closed
        </td>                       
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            test3
        </td>
        <td>
            06/10/2017
        </td>
        <td>
            123
        </td>
        <td>
            closed
        </td>                       
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you also post your HTML?

Comment: So you want to check column 2 values and get the ones with only number?

Comment: Yes exactly that was my question

Comment: Check out the answer now

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = //value of the column;
if(Math.floor(x) == x && $.isNumeric(x)){
//do the code
}
```

You gotta get them go into a loop one by one, check with above code and get the numeric one out.

**Edit:** Maybe this is what you trying to achive. just click the filter button and see. [**DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=d5100ed254b40f5d79dcf6142d7bb756)

Comment: Exactly, but how can I get the value of the column in this function?

Comment: Can you please share html as well. I belive this will be simple if you do.

Comment: This works perfectly as a search .. but it cannot work with my code above and draw for me the table. Search function and draw are called once and the hole table is filtered and drawn.